How to stop docker from creating empty folders on missing secrets files
I'm running docker compose 4.33.1 on Windows 10 and I noticed a strange behavior when using secrets in docker compose. If a secrets is defined but its file is missing, docker will simply create an empty folder with the same name as the missing secrets file and then go on pretending everything is OK. Well it's not so how do I stop this madness?
You can test this easily:

create a folder
have this docker-compose.yml:

version: "3.8"

services:
 testy:
   image: "node:18"
   entrypoint: cat /run/secrets/test_secret
   secrets:
     - test_secret

secrets:
 test_secret:
   file: ./secret.txt


run docker compose up
watch new folder created called secret.txt
notice in the logs: testy-1  | cat: /run/secrets/test_secret: Is a directory

